# How to display an error sign on the Package when the Package has wrong information?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

As you know, If package has a compile error then the package display an error sign.
Error sign means Red circle with 'X'.

My package has some other type file. (It is not a Java file.)
If user modify the file then My plugin will inspect the file.
And should display error sign on the package if the file has wrong information.

How can I display the error sign?