# How can I show the Problem Marker properly? It is not displayed Text Editor and Problem View

Tags: eclipse, markers, eclipse-plugin

I got many ideas from previous question ([How to display an error sign on the Package when the Package has wrong information?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3178996/how-to-display-an-error-sign-on-the-package-when-the-package-has-wrong-informatio))

But the Problem Marker is not displayed.

The resource I'm interested in, is an XML file.

So I added a listener for PRE_BUILD, using the following code:

```
addResourceChangedListener(xxx, IResourceChangeEvent.PRE_BUILD)
```

It works fine. Now I'm trying to add a Problem Marker.

```
IMarker marker = file.createMarker(PROBLEM_ID);
marker.setAttribute(IMarker.SEVERITY, IMarker.SEVERITY_ERROR);
marker.setAttribute(IMarker.MESSAGE, "Error Message");
marker.setAttribute(IMarker.CHAR_START, 5);
marker.setAttribute(IMarker.CHAR_END, 6);
marker.setAttribute(IMarker.LINE_NUMBER, 5);
```

Above code is executed. But the Problem Marker is not displayed on the Editor and Problem views.
How can I show the Problem Marker properly?

Comment: Thanks it was the same problem for me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add your marker upon `IResourceChangeEvent.PRE_BUILD` I could imagine the problem is that before a build, all markers are cleared - so perhaps your new markers are cleared immediately so you don't even see them. I'd give it a try with `IResourceChangeEvent.POST_BUILD`.

Also, are you using the correct problem ID when creating the marker? Because in your code you use `createMarker(PROBLEM_ID)`, not `createMarker(IMarker.PROBLEM)`.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I used 'POST_BUILD' also. I have looked in to this problem from the beginning. Finally I got the Problem Marker. The reason of that is "PROBLEM_ID" in the code. It is different with id of extension. Whatever thanks for your response again.